# how to theme commerce product variation

Tags: theming, commerce

How to theme product variation.

I'm trying to find a tpl file but I cannot figure it out.

Basicaly, I would like to override the Size Field. I would like to add a link beside the size field.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Which TPLs have you tried already? Can you provide maybe a bit more info?

Comment: See suggestion from [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/129310/1908).

Comment: You should be using a product displays, which is a node. Then you can just use node templates.